# PyQt5 Selenium Gecko Driver Built App not working for distribution

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, pyqt5, geckodriver

I have built an App based on pyqt5 and Selenium Gecko driver and Created an exe file using pyinstaller. It works like a charm on my system. The same exe doesn't work on other systems who do not have anything installed like selenium, python or pyqt5. Pyinstaller docs says that I can distribute the exe file to anyone but that didn't work in my case. Am I missing anything here. Need more suggestions from experts on the ground who dealt with it. Please help. I didn't see any errors when I ran the app in Command Prompt too.

Comment: What does  *other systems* mean?

Comment: On another machine to whom I distributed the app.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear, what OS have these other machines?

Comment: It's a windows 7 32bit

Comment: And what is the OS of your machine where you generated the .exe?

Comment: It's a windows 7 64bit os

Comment: Well there is the problem, an executable generated on a 64-bit machine can not be run on a 32bit machine. I recommend generating the .exe on a 32-bit machine since the generated .exe is 32 bits can be run on a 64bit machine

Comment: Will give it a try. Hopefully it should help. Will keep you posted.

Comment: Just tried execution of the app which I generated on 32bit Windows 7 on a 64bit machine Windows 7 didn't work either.

Comment: okay, maybe you have not done the deployment correctly, you could indicate which command you use to general the executable and the files that are generated in the dist folder. Sometimes pyinstaller does not link all the libraries (mainly the system libraries) so in that case it is better to use the dependency walker tool that tells you that .dll, .lib, etc. is missing.

Comment: Will give it a try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191492/discussion-between-john-k-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: Used Dependency walker and noticed some dlls are missing. How to add the missing DLLs ?

Comment: Search the dlls in your OS and copy next to your executable

Comment: I have made the required changes as told by you. Now a quick question, will it work on Windows10 64bit OS?

Comment: I think so, if it does not work then run Dependency walker to see if there are missing some dll but it is very unlikely that something is missing

Comment: Tried all the options from various sources, still unable to get it work on other machine even which has the same system configurations as the one which I am using. Found No errors on exe...verified using dependency walker. I can share the code with you. Needed your help.

Comment: Have you analyzed with *Dependency walker* on the other machine?

Comment: Yes found no errors.

Comment: Have you copied the Geckodriver on the other machine? Are you sure that the Geckodriver route is correct? Does your code have enough guards to analyze in which case there may be an exception? As you see there are a lot of possibilities. I recommend you create a log file that shows how the SW is working and there you can know at least where it was executed.

Comment: Maybe you are throwing the problem to pyinstaller and the error is caused by your code, we can not know without an MCVE